# How to limit the scope of a for statement in a Python oneliner?

Tags: python

Assuming I pass a oneliner like `for i in range(0,3):print "a";print "b"` to `python -c`, how can I limit the scope (not a good word, but the best I can think of) of the `for` loop to the first `print`, i.e. make the invokation print

```
a
a
a
b
```

instead of

```
a
b
a
b
a
b
```

Placing brackets around the first `print` or the `for` loop and the first `print` causes `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`.

Using identation characters fails due to

```
> python -c 'for i in range(0,3):\n  print "a"\nprint "b"'
  File "<string>", line 1
    for i in range(0,3):\n  print "a"\nprint "b"
                                               ^
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character
```

maybe I'm doing it wrong (the use uncommon use of `;` is much more intuitive but causes the problem I try to solve with this question).

The described outputs are examples, I'm not seeking for other solution to printing `aaab`.

Comment: When you write `'\n'` the shell doesn't interpret the escape sequence and Python sees literally backslash-n. Use `$'...'` string syntax to get the shell to pass newlines: `python -c $'for i in range(0,3):\n  print "a"\nprint "b"'`

Comment: You could use a comprehension, for instance: `[print('a') for i in range(0, 3)]; print('b')`

Comment: @wowserx ditto on list comprehension. Though this only works on Python 3 where `print` acts as a function.

Comment: to do it in python 2, `from __future__ import print_function`.